# RSStail crashes with segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault, rss-reader

I'm trying to monitor an RSS feed using rsstail (https://github.com/flok99/rsstail), by piping the url from rsstail into another program. For some reason, rsstail crashes after a few minutes with Segmentation Fault 11. I have no idea why it would be crashing, and there are no reports online that seem to indicate that rsstail has any issues with segfaults on OSX.

How should I be going about figuring out this segfault? I'm considering debugging rsstail using gcb, but this might be overkill for something which by all rights shouldn't be happening.

If any one has an alternative to rsstail that produces command line output, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: I just found `rsstail` and found it does the same thing after the sleep period is over.  Sad that almost 8 years later the same thing is happening.